# Getting value from textbox with variant in VBA

Tags: vba, textbox, null

In my project I am trying to use a function that will return the text or value from any control.  I have this in the code of the actual form.

```
Function GetVar(whatbox As Control) As Variant
    'get value from textbox or checkbox
    whatbox.SetFocus
    If whatbox.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        GetVar = whatbox.Text
    Else
        GetVar = whatbox.Value
    End If
End Function
```

Now, I call it like this:

```
vIssuesPerMonth = GetVar(Me.NumberofCopies)
vCostIssuePrint = GetVar(Me.CostIssuePrint)
vCostIssueMail = GetVar(Me.CostIssueMail)
vSurcharge = GetVar(Me.Surcharge)
vSurchargeNonMember = GetVar(Me.SurchargeNonMember)
```

Then I do some math with the values.

```
vAvCostPerPrint = vCostIssuePrint / vIssuesPerMonth
vAvCostPerMail = vCostIssueMail / vIssuesPerMonth
```

My problem is that the `GetVar` isn't working and it returns "" and so the math fails with a "type mismatch" error.

If I look at the values during debug, it says `whatbox` is null, even though I've sent the right name of the control.  It seems like `me.controlname` isn't being passed properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which case is returning `""`? When it's not a `TextBox` or always?

Comment: The function seems to always trigger with the `if` and not the `else`.  In the debugger, the values are empty - that is, there's no value.  I can't tell if it is returning "" or null.  This is with textboxes.  I'd have to search for an example for a combobox or something else, but right now I'd like to solve for a textbox.

Comment: It seems like `Me.controlname` is not being properly gotten.

Comment: Have you tried returning the CDbl(whatbox.Text)?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `SetFocus`?

Comment: I think I have to use `SetFocus` because I am calling the function from inside the code.  I seem to remember something to do with it not fetching the values unless it setfocus first.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ What is `CDbl` ?

Comment: If I use msgbox(whatbox.text) it gives me a blank messagebox.

Comment: `CDbl` is VBA's built-in conversion function for converting something to a `Double` value. It's only worth using if you're sure what you're converting hsa something representable as a `Double`.

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure why it doesn't work.  I fixed the tables though so they always provide values and *THEN* everything works.  But I can't get it to not break if any of the values are empty.

Comment: @BGM actually, reading better the question, no conversion is worth if you already get the MsgBox empty. Here it's all about debugging. What I would suggest is: 1) Are you sure you want to pass the argument by reference and not by value (i.e. `ByVal whatbox As Control`)? Maybe you expect it to be filled but you're actually emptying it  in some other parts of your code; 2) Whatever the control is, what you see it's the property `.Text`; the property `.Value` might be equal to text, or may be not. 3) Have you added a watch to the input control to make sure the name is the one you want?